# Javascript regex escape dot following digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to test a string which should start with any number of digits but not followed by a dot, so I come up these regs, code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4S938/):

```
var startwith = "some string";
    reg1 = new RegExp("^" + startWith + "[0-9]+(?!\\.)"),
    reg2 = new RegExp("^" + startWith + "\d+(?!\\.)");

var text = "11.1";

console.log(reg1.test(text), reg2.test(text)); // result true, false
```

I started with `reg1`, but it fails to return the correct result, so I was just trying the `reg2`. Surprisingly, the result is correct, but what confuses me is that the two regs return different result, while the patterns are basically equivalent. Anybody have any ideas? all thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: does this work for a replacement for reg1?  `new RegExp("^(0-9)+(?!\\.)")`

Comment: Why are you writing `\\.`, but just `\d`? What is the difference?

Comment: @kobi, good question, but with single backslash won't work for some reason, which I don't know.

Comment: `RegExp` constructor requires double slash so `\\d` instead of `\d` and `\\.` instead of `\.` since it accepts a string in constructor. One backslash is for Javascript string and 2nd one is for Javascript regex engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var re = /^\d+(?!\.)\b/;
```

Problem is that in your regex without word boundary regex matches only first `1` of `11.1` and since next one is not a dot it returns true. You need to force it match till a word boundary is reached.

#### [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dX6wA3/1)

Comment: looks promising. will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Start with any digit not followed by a dot:

```
if (/^\d(?!\.)/.test(yourString)) {
    // It matches!
} else {
    // Nah, no match...
}
```

Comment: sorry, not only single digits, but multiple digits.